# How to properly design a datatable?

Tags: javascript, css, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable and I want to separate the data info the to pagination when accessing my site on my phone. My problem is in my current datatable the datainfo and pagination buttons were inline (please see image). What I wanted to achieve is the datainfo will be separated with the pagination like in the second image.

[Here is the image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYeBl.png)
[Here is the image of what I wanted to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c38Zw.png)

Here is the javascript I used to initialize the datatable:

```
var table = jQuery('#datatable').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "scrollY": false,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "fixedHeader": {
        "header": false,
        "footer": false
    },
    "lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
    "columnDefs": [
        { "width": "150px", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "150px", "targets": 1 },
        { "width": "200px", "targets": 2 }
    ],
    "language": {
        "processing": "Processing...",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "First",
            "last": "Last",
            "next": "Next",
            "previous": "Previous"
        },
        "emptyTable": "No data found",
        "searchPlaceholder": "Search...",
        "search": ""
    }
});
```

Here is my CSS used for the datatable info and pagination:

```
.dataTables_paginate {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.dataTables_info {
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: #bcbec0;
}

.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled {
    color: #d7d9e0;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: auto;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.next, .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.previous {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 36px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #a4a6a8;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out, color .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out, color .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out, color .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Need your css for the buttons to answer :)

Comment: @V.Volkov sorry, I forgot I updated my question and included the CSS I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve that :)
1. Try removing `position: absolute;` from `.dataTables_paginate`
2. Or try adding `top:60px;` to the same `.dataTables_paginate`
3. Or try adding `margin-top:60px;` to the same `.dataTables_paginate`
Also you can add one of the changes to the end of your css block and cover inside `@media`, so that it covers only ~mobile resolution.

```css
@media (max-width:640px) {
  .dataTables_paginate {
    margin-top:60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: it ok now is there a way to center the pagination?

Comment: sure :)
which option did you use?

Comment: I changed the position of .dataTables_paginate to relative the problem now is how can I center the pagination?

Comment: Try adding `display:block; float:none;` along with mentioned margins, or try adding `text-align:center;` to parent element.

Answer (score 0):

one easy way to act on this is to provide a margin to the data info. as the info and pagination is overlapping try adding a margin to that one. and if the .dataTables_paginate  is the class for whole pagination bar then try adding top to that aswell. hope it helps.